# java.lang.NumberFormatException using parseInt

Tags: java

I'm trying to take a digit from a string and perform operations on it. This is the relevant code I'm working on (updated):

```
    String cardNumber;
    String curNum;
    long currentNum;
    int firstNum;
    int randNum;
    int i;
    long sum = 0; 

 while (i <= 15) {
            //Delete this line if it doesnt work
            currentNum = Long.parseLong(cardNumber.substring(i));
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            //currentNum = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.charAt(i));
            currentNum = currentNum * 2;
            if (currentNum > 9) {
                currentNum = currentNum - 9;
                sum = sum + currentNum;
            }
            else {
                //currentNum = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.charAt(i));  
                sum = sum + currentNum;
            }   
            i++;
        }
        long lastVal = 10 - (sum % 10);
        char charNum = (char) lastVal;
        //add int to char statement here
        cardNumber = cardNumber + charNum;
    }
        System.out.println(cardNumber);

        userNum--;
    }
```

The // code is another option I was working on and didn't want to lose, so if there's a way to make it work using that, that's great! The error message this code returns is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "64406849400888"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692)
at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
at MasterCardGenerator.main(MasterCardGenerator.java:54)

Comment: `267574698286122` is maybe too big to be an `int` ?

Comment: @hev1 but he uses it: `currentNum = parseInt(....);` and later `sum = sum + currentNum;` (but I admit it is confusing because of the line break before parseInt)

Answer (score 2):

You said you're trying to take "a" digit from a string. If that's truly the case, and you are trying to examine `cardNumber` one digit at a time,  then you want `cardNumber.substring(i, i+1)` instead of `cardNumber.substring(i)`.

Read the javadocs for [`substring(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) and [`substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the range string you are trying to format is larger than range of `int`.

To solve this problem, you need to change the line `Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(i));` with `Long.parseLong(cardNumber.substring(i));`.

See the range off different data types [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#:%7E:text=long%3A%20The%20long%20data%20type,value%20of%20264%2D1.). Also you can see, for `int` see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) the [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)
and for `long` see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) the [`Long.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE)

**UPDATED**

As per updated question, String passed is `64406849400888` so valid index for `i` are `0 <= i <= 13`. Apart from that above code looks fine. `64406849400888` can be parsed in `long`. See [it the parsing here](https://ideone.com/lx3Jxl)

Comment: Hi! I just tried that and I'm getting a similar error message! Just to make sure, the code was supposed to look like this, correct? `while (i <= 15) {
    currentNum = Long.parseLong(cardNumber.substring(i));
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
    //currentNum = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.charAt(i));
    currentNum = currentNum * 2;
    if (currentNum > 9) {
     currentNum = currentNum - 9;
     sum = sum + currentNum;
    }
    else {
     //currentNum = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.charAt(i)); 
     sum = sum + currentNum;
    } 
    i++;
   }`.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting on the previous comment, it wouldn't let me fix anything.

Comment: @JennaCrist What is the type of `currentNum` and `sum`. It should also be `long`.

Comment: They're both `long` type!

Comment: @JennaCrist Can you add here updated code and exception log?

Comment: @JennaCrist As per updated question, String passed is `64406849400888` so valid index for `i` are `0 <= i <= 13`. Apart from that above code looks fine. `64406849400888` can be parsed in `long`. See [it the parsing here](https://ideone.com/lx3Jxl). Can you provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the domain of integers is between [-2^31,2^31[, indeed between [-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647]. A possible solution is to parse the string using `Long.parseLong(arg)`

```
public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
         System.out.println("Integer.MAX_VALUE: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
         System.out.println("Long.MAX_VALUE: " + Long.MAX_VALUE);
         Long var = Long.parseLong("267574698286122");
         System.out.println("Printing content of 'var': " + var);
     }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE: 2147483647
Long.MAX_VALUE: 9223372036854775807
Printing content of 'var': 267574698286122
```